# Get-LocalGroupMember equivalent API

Tags: visual-studio, api, powershell

I'm trying to get a list of all users in the local groups in my system using powershell.`Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators"`

This is working properly.

I would just like to know if there is any built-in API/function in C++ to get this list.